# C# ASP.net MVC 2 PDF Parsing Program

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a program that parses a pdf, .doc, or .docx file so I can pull the information and put it into a database.  I just don't want to type it all out one by one.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products from [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) and the [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) will be usefull... but still you will need to do a lot of coding for parsing and storing in database.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibly free solution is [Docotic.PDF Library](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/). I haven't actually used yet, but I found it a few days ago while looking for my own PDF solution. I sent a question and got a quick and helpful response.